# XML Empty value for INT Type

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

```
 <xs:element name="EmpVisionPlanExist" minOccurs ="0">
 <xs:simpleType>
 <xs:union memberTypes="INT EmptyStrings "/>
 </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="Int">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:pattern value="[01]"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="EmptyStrings">
<xs:restriction base="xs:token">
<xs:enumeration value=""/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

if  i give my xml as

```
<EmpVisionPlanExist></EmpVisionPlanExist>
```

it is cought in xsd validation.
But i want it to be allowed .

Comment: Is there a \n in the element i.e. are the start and end tags on different lines

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you define your `EmptyStrings` type like this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="EmptyStrings">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="0" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

However, the orthodox way to allow a non-string simple type element to be blank is to make the element nillable:

```
<xs:element name="EmpVisionPlanExist" type="INT" nillable="true" />
```

If you go this route, you'll need to include the `xsi:nil` attribute on nillable elements that are blank:

```
<EmpVisionPlanExist xsi:nil="true"></EmpVisionPlanExist>   <!-- valid -->
<EmpVisionPlanExist></EmpVisionPlanExist>                  <!-- not valid -->
```

`xsi` here refers to the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Lastly, if you are going to define a type that can only have the values `0` or `1`, I think "Bit" is a better name for it than "Int". I also wonder why you don't just use a Boolean type, which is a standard type and allows the values `true`, `false`, `0`, and `1`.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the point of xsi:nil. My own preference when defining an element that contains an integer or nothing is to define it as list-of-integer with maxLength="1". But I do hate restricting integers with a pattern facet, especially when a value range will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct your schema by s/INT/Int/ and deleting minOccurs="0", then your instance is valid (as validated by Saxon). What error message were you getting, and what schema processor were you using?